# If certain URL parameter exists, post certain HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make certain code appear instead if the URL contains certain parameters. My code works except for the bottom part, where the parameter equaling SOLD should display different code. Where am I wrong?

```
$('<div class="properties-found-alt" style="margin-top: 50px; padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 0px;"><h2 class="h2" id="ch2" style="font-size: 1.5rem; font-weight: bold;">'+loc+" "+type+' For Sale</h2></div>').insertAfter(".sub-bar-tabs:first")[0];
var str = $(".properties-found span")[0].innerHTML.split(' ')[0]+" "+type+" For Sale";
$(".properties-found span")[0].innerHTML = str;
// $(".properties-found span")[1].innerHTML = str;

if(getUrlParameter('search_status') && getUrlParameter('search_status') != "SOLD"){
    $('<div class="properties-found-alt" style="margin-top: 50px; padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 0px;"><h2 class="h2" id="ch2" style="font-size: 1.5rem; font-weight: bold;">Sold '+type+" in "+loc+'</h2></div>').insertAfter(".sub-bar-tabs:first")[0];
    var str = $(".properties-found span")[0].innerHTML.split(' ')[0]+" "+type+" For Sale";
    $(".properties-found span")[0].innerHTML = str;
}
```

Comment: You need to post the contents of `getUrlParameter`.  That's probably where the problem lies.  Also post an example URL where you expect the bottom part to be displayed.

Comment: Use `!==` instead of `!=` doesn't mean that's solve the problem but it should be `!==`

Comment: Also `getUrlParameter('search_status').trim() !== "SOLD"` you can add `.trim()` to avoid any white spaces

Comment: This is where the code should display. See the "listingresultsheader.js" in source. Thanks so much! https://www.bothellhomes.com/search/results/?city=Bellevue&neighborhood=all&type=res&type=con&search_status=SOLD&sold_price_min=all&sold_price_max=600000&sold_within=6&area_min=all&beds_min=all&baths_min=all&lot_size_min=all&style=all&short_sale=all&school_district=all&waterfront=all&view=all&architecture=all&year_built_min=all&year_built_max=all&parking_spaces_min=all&parking_type=all&master_on_main=all

Comment: No I meant post the code for `getUrlParameter` here on StackOverflow.  You posted a bit of JavaScript here but you didn't include the `getUrlParameter` function.

Comment: s = new URLSearchParams(new URL(location).searchParams); then getUrlParameter = p => s.get(p); and  hasUrlParameter = p => s.has(p);

Comment: I can't post the code it's too long. It's within this file (file only contains code for this so no other code to sift through): https://u.realgeeks.media/lookinwa/js/listingresultsheader.js

Comment: You said it should display at that link containing `type=res&type=con&search_status=SOLD&sold_price_min=all`.  But the bottom part will clearly only display if `search_status` is NOT equal to `SOLD`.

Comment: What I want it to do is display certain HTML if the URL contains "search_status=SOLD" if that makes more sense.

Comment: Right but your code has `getUrlParameter('search_status') != "SOLD")`, so it will display that bottom part only if `search_status` is **NOT** `SOLD`.  Try changing that to `getUrlParameter('search_status') == "SOLD")`

Comment: I fixed it!!!!!! Thanks so much.